# How do you cast video/content to your television from Amazon Prime Video app?

Tags: streaming, chromecast, screencast, amazon-video

I would like to get my video and content to my television from my Android phone or tablet but [the Amazon Prime Video app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient&hl=en) does not support Chromecast.

**How do you cast video/content to your television from Amazon Prime Video app?**

Comment: this question has 1000+ views... but no upvotes... if you viewers find this question useful... please upvote.

Comment: Latest Prime Video android app has the capability to cast videos ..pls check

Comment: @TechDog thanks for the tip! i can't check right now but I will when i get home. (maybe the cold war between amazon and google is over...???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Prime Videos now supports casting to Chromecast straight from inside the official app, it does have a stupid problem that you can't use the phone to adjust the TV volume like you would usually do with Chromecast, it comes up with a stupid surround error when you try, and you have to use the actual TV remote to adjust the volume, but for the sake of this question, it works as mentioned above.

For future reference, I am using an HTC U12 Plus with the lasted firmware, which for this device is Android Pie, and I am using the latest version of Amazon Prime Videos, which is 3.0.268.28447.

Answer (score 2):

## 2018-09-13 update

Short answer is: **you can't**. You can use a laptop (windows/linux/mac/chrome-os) with Chrome browser to cast. Or you can buy an Amazon-Fire hardware device.

Long answer: the "cast your screen" solution now seems to be broken.

Broken? Exactly how?:

- the audio plays from the TV screen
- the video does not play form the TV screen (TV is black where the video should be)

So for android devices, I don't know of any way to cast from your Android device to a Chromecast.

## 2017-12-12 Use the Android feature called "cast your screen".

### how to use "cast your screen"

- turn on your TV and Chromecast
- make sure your chromecast/phone are connected to the same wifi
- unlock your phone
- pull down the "quick settings" drawer from the top
- touch the "cast screen/audio" button
- your chromecast should now display what is on your Android device's screen
- open the Amazon Prime Video app
- play your content on your phone and the audio/video will show up on your television

Official directions from Google on how to cast your screen: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2865484?hl=en

### background

The [Amazon Prime Video app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient&hl=en) does not support streaming to Chromecast from the app.

However a less well-known feature of newer Android versions is the ability to "cast your Android device's screen and audio" to the television. Or to put it another way you can "mirror your display" from your Android device to the television.

The "cast your Android device" feature is supported for later versions of Android 4.x (I don't know what version exactly).

### caveat

- The "cast your screen" requires your Android device to be on, screen on, unlocked
- because "cast your screen" mirrors your android device

  - the battery usage is high
  - the wifi bandwidth used is high (has to send the audio/video from the internet to your phone, then from your phone to the router, then from the router to the Chromcast)
- the resolution on the television depends on your phone's pixel resolution
- "cast your screen" can cut out for various reasons and does not seem to be as reliable as normal Chromecast

Comment: non-android solutions are: (1.) buy a product that connects to the TV and download the Amazon app (i used to use an xbox with the amazon app before I found this solution) (2.) use an Amazon-Fire product (3.) use a laptop with Chrome browser and click "cast to screen"

Answer (score 1):

As of now, it is possible to cast the contents of that app using Miracast, provided that both the Android phone and the TV supports that. I know for sure OnePlus 5, OnePlus 6, Redmi 5A and Redmi Note 5 Pro and Sony Bravia (don't know model number) supports Miracast, but Motorola G4 Plus doesn't.

I have used Amazon Prime app on the four devices personally to cast them using Miracast. I used inbuilt cast option under Settings app to cast, instead of doing it through the app.

**Note:** It is also possible to cast Netflix using Miracast, though you won't get any video, but only the audio.

Comment: Just like Chromecast, there are sticks in the market (such as on AliExpress) which  provide Miracast support when the TV doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

The new Amazon Prime Video app does definitely not support Miracast!

My Android Device is a Huawei P10 Lite with MirrorShare function. My TV is a Sharp with Miracast function and they can be connected.

There was no problem with the former Amazon APP (shopping) which Prime Video was a part of.

I can mirror other content e.g. Netflix, private videos, whatsoever, I can see my Android display on TV, can launch the app but only the sound comes from TV and I can see all of the Android-related displays like "stop", "continue" "forward and backward" and so on but the video is not shown.